# Stop autoplay of background video on mobile devices

Tags: css, jquery-mobile, mobile

I am working on a very simple website with fullscreen video playing as background (auto played when the website was opened). For mobile size, I am switching the video background into a images slideshow, simply I just showed the slideshow and hide the video on a mobile screen size

However I noticed on some mobile browsers, the autoplay video will still open automatically in a video player when I open the web page. I think I might need to either remove the video or stop the autoplay attribute when on mobile. Any suggestion I can make small changes to achieve it?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: i think this is css issue

Answer (score 0):

Try writing a simple JavaScript code to force stop the autoplay feature. Use this syntax

```
var vid = document.getElementById("ID of video element");
vid.autoplay = false;
```